# Can "when" also accept an expression?

Tags: kotlin

kotlin noob here. This is a sample code from kotlin's site

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val language = if (args.size == 0) "EN" else args[0]
    println(when (language) {
        "EN" -> "Hello!"
        "FR" -> "Salut!"
        "IT" -> "Ciao!"
        else -> "Sorry, I can't greet you in $language yet"
    })
}
```

Now if I modify the above code into the following:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(when (if (args.size == 0) "EN" else args[0]) {
        "EN" -> "Hello!"
        "FR" -> "Salut!"
        "IT" -> "Ciao!"
        else -> "Sorry, I can't greet you in $language yet"
    })
}
```

I get an error. Why? Isn't `when` supposed to also accept an expression? In this case the result of the `if` condition?

P.S I tried this in https://try.kotlinlang.org/ And the error I get is just a simple `error:` with no further explanation

Comment: What error do you get? Is it about `language` reference being unresolved?

Comment: I tried this in https://try.kotlinlang.org/ And the error I get is just a simple `error:` No further explanation

Comment: The error is explained in the @yole's answer. Sorry about the error reporting experience in try.kotlinlang.org, we'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use an expression in `when`. Your second example does not compile because you refer to the `language` variable which is no longer defined.

Comment: Hey can you elaborate on that? I have deleted the whole `language` variable.

Comment: @StefanGolubović Oh How did I missed that. Of course. Thank you so much It runs just fine now.